# Populate a single SQL Server column with data from multiple columns and add prefix to value

Tags: sql, sql-insert

***Update*** I ended up just using an insert into before I insert the Values and assigned it p_id = 0, the result is as I need it to be. Thanks!

```
INSERT INTO table2 (p_id,value)
Values(0,@@SYS=DEV');
```

I'm trying to combine 3 columns from Table1 and place the values in Table2 in a single column, but I also want to prefix the values with A, & B, & C, as depicted below. P_Id is auto incrementing.

**Table1**

```
+---------+--------+-----------+
| Emp_ID  | Status | hire_date | 
+---------+--------+-----------+
| 12345   | happy  | 10/10/2005|
| 54321   | sad    | 12/01/2009|
+---------+--------+-----------+
```

Insert into Table2....

I thought I could just inserted a static line in this solution but it duplicated on every new emp_id whereas I only need it one time in the top row.

```
+------+--------------+
| P_Id |    Info      | 
+---------------------+
| 1    | @@=Dev       |
| 2    | A,12345      |
| 3    | B,happy      |
| 4    | C,10/10/2005 | 
| 5    | A,54321      |
| 6    | B,sad        |
| 7    | C,12/01/2009 |
+------+--------------+
```

Any help is greatly appreciated! Environment is SQL Server 2008.

Comment: Have you considered using a view instead of denormalizing your table into a different structure?  When you keep the same set of data in two tables, you now have to worry about the two staying in sync with each other...

Comment: I am only using this table to generate a properly formatted import .txt file for the system I am interfacing with, this will just be overwritten each day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do this in one select, like this:

```
with cte as (
    select T.Emp_ID, C.Value
    from Table1 as T
        outer apply (values
            ('A,' + cast(T.Emp_ID as varchar(max))),
            ('B,' + T.Status),
            ('C,' + convert(varchar(10), T.hire_date, 103))
        ) as C(Value)
)
-- insert into Table2
select
    row_number() over(order by Emp_ID, Value) as p_id,
    Value
from cte
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f445a/6)</kbd>**

Comment: This is awesome it works perfectly!  Do you have any suggestions how I would add a string to row one prior to this populating the table? (i.e row 1 should be always be re-written to p_id = 1, value = @@SYS=DEV ?

Answer (score 0):

```
Insert Into Table2
Select 'A, '+Convert(varchar(10),Emp_ID) From Table1
Union
Select 'B, '+Status From Table1
Union
Select 'C, '+convert(varchar(12),Hire_Date) From Table1
```